# How can I get my information to display into a link <a href> or a <div>?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

The issue I am having is that I need the search results to be displayed in a link or a . Right now they display into a text input field. When I try to change it to a link or div no text is generated. I am almost certain it has to do with the java/jquery script I have. The script I am using is an open source script that I need for simple reasons.

What I have tried is changing the element in which the script calls for from an input to a div or a href. I have googled and tried to find some sort of reference to which the script selects what elements to display the code into and the only thing I can identify as being the problem is, "userid = ui.item.value; // selected id to input".

index.php - Script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){

            $(document).on('keydown', '.username', function() {

                var id = this.id;
                var splitid = id.split('_');
                var index = splitid[1];

                $( '#'+id ).autocomplete({
                    source: function( request, response ) {
                        $.ajax({
                            url: "getDetails.php",
                            type: 'post',
                            dataType: "json",
                            data: {
                                search: request.term,request:1
                            },
                            success: function( data ) {
                                response( data );
                            }
                        });
                    },
                    select: function (event, ui) {
                        $(this).val(ui.item.label); // display the selected text
                        var userid = ui.item.value; // selected id to input

                        // AJAX
                        $.ajax({
                            url: 'getDetails.php',
                            type: 'post',
                            data: {userid:userid,request:2},
                            dataType: 'json',
                            success:function(response){

                                var len = response.length;

                                if(len > 0){

                                    var name = response[0]['name'];
                                    var displayid = response[0]['displayid'];



                                    document.getElementById('name_'+index).value = name;
                                    document.getElementById('displayid_'+index).value = displayid;


                                }

                            }
                        });

                        return false;
                    }
                });
            });

            // Add more
            $('#addmore').click(function(){

                // Get last id 
                var lastname_id = $('.tr_input input[type=text]:nth-child(1)').last().attr('id');
                var split_id = lastname_id.split('_');

                // New index
                var index = Number(split_id[1]) + 1;

                // Create row with input elements
                var html = "<tr class='tr_input'><td><input type='text' class='username' id='username_"+index+"' placeholder='Enter username'></td><td><input type='text' class='name' id='name_"+index+"' ></td><td><input type='text' class='displayid' id='displayid_"+index+"' ></td></tr>";

                // Append data
                $('tbody').append(html);

            });
        });

    </script>
```

index.php - Html

```
    <div class="container">

        <table border='1' style='border-collapse: collapse;'>
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Search</th>    
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Display ID</th>

            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <tr class='tr_input'>
                <td><input type='text' class='username' id='username_1' placeholder='Enter username'></td>              
                <td><input type='text' class='name' id='name_1' readonly></td>
                <td><input type='text' class='displayid' id='displayid_1' readonly></td>

            </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <br>
        <input type='button' value='Add more' id='addmore'>
    </div>
```

getDetails.php

```
$request = $_POST['request'];   // request

// Get username list
if($request == 1){
    $search = $_POST['search'];

    $query = "SELECT * FROM item_template WHERE name like'%".$search."%'";
    $result = mysqli_query($con,$query);

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result) ){
        $response[] = array("value"=>$row['entry'],"label"=>$row['name']);
    }

    // encoding array to json format
    echo json_encode($response);
    exit;
}

// Get details
if($request == 2){
    $userid = $_POST['userid'];
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM item_template WHERE entry=".$userid;

    $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

    $users_arr = array();

    while( $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result) ){
        $userid = $row['entry'];
        $name = $row['name'];
        $displayid = $row['displayid'];


        $users_arr[] = array("entry" => $userid, "name" => $name,"displayid" => $displayid);
    }

    // encoding array to json format
    echo json_encode($users_arr);
    exit;
}
```

I except the selector is wrong in the script, where it selects where to copy the text to.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to use `innerHTML` instead of `value`.

```
document.getElementById('name_'+index).innerHTML = name;
document.getElementById('displayid_'+index).innerHTML = displayid;
```

and change the `input` tag to `div` tag. You might want to read more about [innerHTML](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_innerhtml.asp).